# Toll Free or Toll-Free on business cards and letterheads

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation

Which is correct for business card and letterhead:

Toll Free:  (800) 000-0000

Toll-Free:  (800) 000-000

Toll free:  (800) 000-0000

Toll-free:  (800) 000-0000

Comment: I jumped the gun and flagged this as spam.  I now realize that it's not spam. However I still believe it should be closed as Off Topic and/or Primarily Opinion based.

Comment: I think ***Toll[-]*** in such constructions is starting to sound really "quaint" these days. In the modern style it's just ***call** free [on 0800...]*. But it's a bit insulting to potential clients (or whoever you give the cards to) to suppose that they don't already know that all 0800 number are free [(even from mobiles now)](http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/news/phones/2015/06/0800-numbers-now-free-to-call-from-mobiles)

Comment: Maybe closed as a duplicate of the question about hyphenating words?

Answer (score 2):

### **toll-free or toll free?**

- The rules for hyphen according to the **APA style**  state the following
  Compound adjective: hyphenate two or more words when they come before a noun they modify and act as a single idea.
  e.g: Toll-free number
  When not used as an adjective, there is no need to hyphenate
  e.g: The number is toll free
  Here, is the link to the source http://www.apastyle.org/learn/faqs/when-use-hyphen.aspx
- **The Chicago Manual of Style**, however, states that Compounds formed with free as second element are hyphenated both before and after a noun.
  The link to the source is http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/images/ch07_tab01.pdf
  So, **according to the CMOS**,hyphen would be used in both cases
  i.e. Toll-free number
  The number is Toll-free

### **Whether to use Toll-free or Toll-Free?**

- Usually, the second word is capitalized if the word is a noun, adjective, or is equally important as the first word.
  e.g: Two-thirds and Mid-September
  This again comes from **APA style**, which mentions the following

> Capitalize all “major” words (nouns, verbs, adjectives, adverbs, and pronouns) in the title/heading, including the second part of hyphenated major words (e.g., Self-Report not Self-report)

- The **CMOS(Section 7.128)** recommends the following

> "subsequent elements are capitalized unless they are articles, prepositions, coordinating conjunctions, or such modifiers as flat, sharp and natural following musical key symbols; second elements attached by hyphens to prefixes are not capitalized unless they are proper nouns or proper adjectives.  If a compound (other than one with a hyphenated prefix) comes at the end of the title, its final element, whatever part of speech it may be, is always capitalized.”

In both the cases, Toll-free is the accepted usage when used with a noun.
For business cards and letter heads Toll-free: (800) is more appropriate

Comment: @choster I have edited the answer based on your comment. Please have a look

Comment: I appreciate you have answered the comment and supplied references. However the answer is now extremely difficult to read and work out what goes with what. Don't bother with "Edit" -- the [edit history](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/292439/revisions) is available anyway -- just organise **all** the information as logically as possible.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I have formatted the answer based on your inputs.

Comment: Looks good to me. +1